# Help with iphone segment control colors

Tags: iphone

I need some help getting the right hex colors to my dev team. I have done some research but it seems less then obvious for how i achieve this

here is the image

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2982102/stack%20overflow.png

you will see what we need the segment control to look like. We dont need it perfect but we are trying to get close.

can you help me with this task, it might also help others in the future color these things correctly

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may help?:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

It creates a UIColor from a C hex number.

Comment: This is awesome, would you be able to send me a screen of what it looks like?

Comment: @Quotient: He didn’t give you a color, he gave you a macro for turning a hex value *into* a color.

Comment: Just give it a shot, plonk the macro in and use a hex straight from your design. Might need a few tries to get the level right, but should be easy enough. (PS need the C 0x on the beginning of your hex)